# Create a table containing all rows of 3 tables join with 3 similar columns [SQL]

Tags: sql, database, join

As the title indicates (in an incorrect way), I would like to create a table bringing together all the lines of 3 different tables, with as common points, their creation date and a folder id (present in each of the 3 tables).

simple schema of the DB : [image of the DB schema with relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gQAK.png)

How would you write this in SQL ?

PS: it's maybe super easy but I'm all new with SQL, sorry !

PS2: don't hesitate if you need more explanations or precisions

Thank you :)

---

What I tried :

```
SELECT product_folder.id AS product_folder_id
pens.brand AS pen_brand
schoolbags.size AS schoolbag_size
notebooks.number_of_pages AS notebook_pages
created_at,
updated_at
FROM product_folders pf
LEFT JOIN product_folders pf ON schoolbags.product_folder_id = pf.id
LEFT JOIN product_folders pf ON pens.product_folder_id = pf.id
LEFT JOIN product_folders pf ON notebooks.product_folder_id = pf.id
```

But it doesn’t return what I ask (an error).

**EDIT :**

The error :
'ERROR:  table name "pf" specified more than once'

The table should look something like this : [image of the table I want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAwo6.png)

More precisely : (*p_f_id = product_folder_id)

```
------------------------------all-products------------------------------

id p_f_id* brand      size    price  nb_of_pages  created_at  updated_at
-- ------- ---------- ------- ------ ------------ ----------- ---------
1  34      Watermark  NULL    34.00  NULL         12-04-2022  15-04-2022
2  22      NULL       medium  40.00  NULL         28-11-2022  29-11-2022
3  18      NULL       NULL    12.00  42           06-09-2022  06-09-2022
```

I know some of the columns will return NULL (ex: pens don't have pages so > NULL) and I'm ok with that.
I just want the column product_folder_id filled with the id of the folder of the different products and the created_at and updated_at columns filled with the date of each rows.

Comment: "it doesn’t return what I ask (an error)" -> Can you please tell us what is the error? (add it to the question with the "Edit" link under the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first error is that you joined multiple times the table `product_folder` with the same alias "pf", you cannot do this because if you want to select fields from any of the joined tables, SQL must know which one you want to select from (that's the goal of an alias). You could for example do:

```
SELECT pf1.id, pf2.id
FROM product_folders pf1
LEFT JOIN product_folders pf2 ON pf2.id = pf1.id
```

It makes no real sense (it will select twice the same id for each row of `product_folders`) but shows you that you must use the aliases in the `SELECT` part and in the `ON` part to distinguish joined tables.

Your main error though is for your case, you don't need to join on the same table, and then you don't need to give aliases. You want to join directly on the tables you want to select the fields from:

```
SELECT product_folder.id AS product_folder_id
pens.brand AS pen_brand
schoolbags.size AS schoolbag_size
notebooks.number_of_pages AS notebook_pages
/*created_at,
updated_at*/
FROM product_folders
LEFT JOIN schoolbags ON schoolbags.product_folder_id = product_folders.id
LEFT JOIN pens ON pens.product_folder_id = product_folders.id
LEFT JOIN notebooks ON notebooks.product_folder_id = product_folders.id
```

I commented `created_at, updated_at` because from the question we cannot know where you want these columns from, as they don't exist in `product_folder`. It could be  `schoolbags.created_at, schoolbags.updated_at` or `pens.created_at, pens.updated_at` or `notebooks.created_at, notebooks.updated_at`, or all of them...

EDIT FOLLOWING MORE INFOS:
Since you have entries in `product_folder` that don't correspond to the 3 joined tables, you must filter relevant results with a `WHERE`.

Additionnally, if each row in `product_folder` corresponds to only one of the 3 joined tables, you can retreive `created_at / updated_at` by testing if the `id` is `null` (or another field) with `IF`.

That would give:

```
SELECT product_folder.id AS product_folder_id,
pens.brand AS pen_brand,
schoolbags.size AS schoolbag_size,
notebooks.number_of_pages AS notebook_pages,
IF(pens.id IS NOT NULL, pens.created_at,
  IF(schoolbags.id IS NOT NULL, schoolbags.created_at, notebooks.created_at)
) as created_at,
IF(pens.id IS NOT NULL, pens.updated_at,
  IF(schoolbags.id IS NOT NULL, schoolbags.updated_at, notebooks.updated_at)
) as updated_at,
FROM product_folders
LEFT JOIN schoolbags ON schoolbags.product_folder_id = product_folders.id
LEFT JOIN pens ON pens.product_folder_id = product_folders.id
LEFT JOIN notebooks ON notebooks.product_folder_id = product_folders.id
WHERE (pens.brand IS NOT NULL OR schoolbags.size IS NOT NULL OR notebooks.number_of_pages IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
I understand what you explain about the joining of tables, and I tried what you suggest. The problem is that it gave me too much rows.
I have 123 rows for schoolbags table, 36 rows for notebooks table and 158 rows for pens table. I would like 123+36+158 = 317 rows. The query you suggest gave 2474 rows.
I edit my questions (just before you answer me) with an example of what the generated table should look like.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out where this number comes from, your edit suggests that each row in `product_folder` corresponds to only one row which is either in `schoolbags` or `notebooks` or `pens`, is it the case? How many rows do you have in `product_folder`? Are there rows that correspond to none of these 3 joined tables?

Comment: You're right, I didn't really explain it.
Each product belongs to a folder, so each product have a product_folder_id.
These 3 products are not the only in the DB. For example, in the folder where pens are, you can find wooden_pencils table, fountain_pens table... and as they are all product similar to pen/pencil, they go to the same folder and have the same folder id.

Comment: @h3lt3r-sk3lt3r I updated my answer with these infos

Comment: Thank you for trying to understand and solve my problem.
I tried with your updated answer but it seems to have an issue with the IF function.
```ERROR:  function if(boolean, timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone) does not exist
LINE 6:  IF(schoolbags.id IS NOT NULL, schoolbags.created_at, notebooks.crea...
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.```

Comment: And when I try the query without the IF statements, it give me another error:
```ERROR:  column "pen_brand" does not exist
LINE 13: WHERE (pen_brand IS NOT NULL OR schoolbag_size IS NOT NULL OR ...``` but, the column exist..

Comment: @h3lt3r-sk3lt3r my bad, I always make this mistake, the WHEN is treated before the SELECT, so you must use the real columns, not the aliases, as in my last edit. Concerning the `IF`, I assumed this was mySQL, but maybe you are using SQL Server? can you confirm before I look for a solution? (I don't know SQL Server well)

Comment: No problem, it works as I want now (with the created_at/updated_at part commented) !
Otherwise, I'm working with PostgreSQL.

Comment: @h3lt3r-sk3lt3r Cool I'm glad I could help you, for the created/updated columns you can check the documentation/stackoverflow for `CASE` in PostgreSQL if `IF` is not supported. You can also accept the answer if it helped you, good luck for the rest!

Comment: Great, I will do that !
Thank you for taking the time to understand and resolve my request Kaddath !

Answer (score 0):

It is not known, what result you want. Some correction to your query may be help to next step

```
SELECT 
   pf.id AS product_folder_id
  ,pens.brand AS pen_brand
  ,schoolbags.size AS schoolbag_size
  ,notebooks.number_of_pages AS notebook_pages
  ,pf.created_at
  ,pf.updated_at
FROM product_folders pf
LEFT JOIN product_folders schoolbags ON schoolbags.product_folder_id = pf.id
LEFT JOIN product_folders pens ON pens.product_folder_id = pf.id
LEFT JOIN product_folders notebooks ON notebooks.product_folder_id = pf.id
```

May be table **product_folders** has name **all_products**, as shown on image. Try this

```
SELECT 
   pf.id AS product_folder_id
  ,pens.brand AS pen_brand
  ,schoolbags.size AS schoolbag_size
  ,notebooks.number_of_pages AS notebook_pages
  ,pf.created_at
  ,pf.updated_at
FROM all_products pf
LEFT JOIN all_products schoolbags ON schoolbags.product_folder_id = pf.id
LEFT JOIN all_products pens ON pens.product_folder_id = pf.id
LEFT JOIN all_products notebooks ON notebooks.product_folder_id = pf.id
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried this but I got another error :

'ERROR:  column schoolbags.product_folder_id does not exist
LINE 8: LEFT JOIN product_folders schoolbags ON schoolbags.product_folder_id = pf.id (with an arrow under the 's' of schoolbags)'

>>> I don't even understand this error because this column exists.

I'm sorry if I didn't clearly explain what I'm searching to have.
Did you see the images linked in the question ?

Comment: The all-products table is the table I want to generate with the 3 tables of different products (pens, schoolbags, notebooks), it doesn't exist yet.
I can't use it in my SQL query.